# How to add shipping price for all individual product

Tags: magento2, product, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, table-rates

I want shipping price for individual product, not depending country, state or anything. For example one product's shipping price is $5 but another one product's shipping price is $8. How to give shipping price for individual product?

Comment: For which shipping method you want to use that price?

Comment: it should get individual fixed-rate + rate from price vs destination.

Comment: so it must be applied for the Tablerate method only?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a product attribute named `base_individual_shipping_price` and one simple plugin for the `Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate` (or other method, or for all methods) where we can read this additional individual price of each product and add it to the Rate.

Here is that plugin code:

> app/code/MageWorx/ShippingPricePerProduct/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate">
        <plugin name="mageworx_individual_product_shipping_price"
                type="MageWorx\ShippingPricePerProduct\Plugin\ChangeShippingMethodPrice"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/MageWorx/ShippingPricePerProduct/Plugin/ChangeShippingMethodPrice.php

```
<?php

namespace MageWorx\ShippingPricePerProduct\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierInterface;

/**
 * Class ChangeShippingMethodPrice
 */
class ChangeShippingMethodPrice
{
    /**
     * Set individual shipping price per product to each shipping rate
     *
     * @param AbstractCarrierInterface $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterCollectRates(
        AbstractCarrierInterface $subject,
        $result,
        RateRequest $request
    ) {
        if (!$result instanceof \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result) {
            return $result;
        }

        $priceSurcharge = 0;
        $items = $request->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            if (!$product) {
                continue;
            }
            $priceSurcharge += (float)$product->getData('base_individual_shipping_price');
        }

        foreach ($result->getAllRates() as $rate) {
            if (!$rate->getData('individual_price_applied')) {
                $individualPrice = $rate->getPrice() + $priceSurcharge;
                $rate->setPrice($individualPrice);
                $rate->setData('individual_price_applied', true);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Or you can [download full example module on GitHub](https://github.com/SiarheyUchukhlebau/MageWorx_ShippingPricePerProduct) with attribute installation.

Here is how it looks inside this plugin (using xDebug):

[image: xDebug view: how plugin works]

Here is individual price set to the product (in admin side):

[image: Individual shipping price attribute in the product edit form]

As you can see the individual price 5.0 was added to the base rate of 15.0 so result price will be 20.0

So here is result on frontend:

[image: result on frontend]

***Note***: 22.0 is price with tax.

Comment: @Siarhey I too going through this scenario. But in my case, it is little bit different. In my case table rate shipping rate should only be applied if there is no individual shipping rate is added for the products.  Can you please help me out here?

Comment: @jithin sure, give me a link for new question

Comment: @skm sure, give me a link for your question

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau here is the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301918/individual-shipping-rate-per-product-along-with-table-rate-magento-2

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau here, I got an individual shipping price field in the advanced pricing.but in checkout it's not working.