# Individual Shipping Rate per product along with Table Rate - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, table-rates

I am using the table rate (price vs destination) shipping method. Along with these data I also need individual shipping rates per product.So the shipping rate from the table-rate should only be used if there is no individual shipping rate is specified for the product. Can anyone help me here

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: And how you will calculate a final price for the cart with both product with individual rate price and without that price? The price must be taken from the individual shipping price of the product if any product have it, is it right?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau ya exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slightly modified plugin from this answer [How to add shipping price for all individual product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301843/how-to-add-shipping-price-for-all-individual-product/301875#301875)

> app/code/MageWorx/ShippingPricePerProduct/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate">
        <plugin name="mageworx_individual_product_shipping_price"
                type="MageWorx\ShippingPricePerProduct\Plugin\ChangeShippingMethodPrice"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/MageWorx/ShippingPricePerProduct/Plugin/ChangeShippingMethodPrice.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MageWorx\ShippingPricePerProduct\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierInterface;

/**
 * Class ChangeShippingMethodPrice
 */
class ChangeShippingMethodPrice
{
    /**
     * Set individual shipping price per product to each shipping rate
     *
     * @param AbstractCarrierInterface $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterCollectRates(
        AbstractCarrierInterface $subject,
        $result,
        RateRequest $request
    ) {
        if (!$result instanceof \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result) {
            return $result;
        }

        $priceSurcharge = 0;
        $items = $request->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            if (!$product) {
                continue;
            }
            $priceSurcharge += (float)$product->getData('base_individual_shipping_price');
        }

        foreach ($result->getAllRates() as $rate) {
            if (!$rate->getData('individual_price_applied')) {
                if ($priceSurcharge > 0) {
                    // Set new price only in case individual price was found
                    $rate->setPrice($priceSurcharge);
                }

                $rate->setData('individual_price_applied', true);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

In this variant we set new price for the table rate only in case when the individual price was found for products in current cart.

**PS:** If this is not your case, please, leave me a comment.

Comment: In my case if individual shipping rate is set for a product then that value should be considered as shipping rate otherwise default value from table rate should be considered.

Comment: @skm this plugin works in same way: if individual shipping price is not found, we using a regular rate; if individual price exists - we use considered individual price. But in case when two products in cart, with individual price and without it, we are using only individual price of the first product and 0 for the second.

Comment: I installed the plugin but the shipping rate always return 0 in the checkout page.

Comment: @skm did you set an individual price for your products in the edit product form?

Comment: Ya I already set the shipping price for the product but it is not appearing in the frontend.

Comment: @skm Is your module available on GitHub or somewhere else? Or you are using example from my repository?

Comment: No, I am just using the example provided by you

Comment: @skm and you set individual price in the advanced price fieldset of the product form?

Comment: Ya I already done it

Comment: could you please help me here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310765/issue-with-adding-product-to-cart-magento2

Comment: Could you please help me here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/314889/how-to-override-magento2-product-tierprice