# Issue with adding product to cart Magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, addtocart

When a user try to add a new product to cart it is working fine. The number of product in cart is getting updated as one. But when he try to add another product to cart, then it is not getting added as a second product.The quantity of the first product is getting incremented. So the cart count is still one.This is happening when he tries to add multiple products. Only the quantity of the first product added to cart is getting updated no new product is being added.This is for logedin users only. I am using custom ajax call to add product to cart.

```
    <?php

namespace V\Catalog\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

/**
 * Class DellPost
 * @package Magebay\Hello\Controller\Index
 */
class AddToCart extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Result page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
     */
    protected $_resultJsonFactory;
    protected $formKey;
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultJson = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create();
        $response = [
            'status'=>'error',
            'message'=>'Error, Please try again'
        ];
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $productId = isset($params['product']) ? (int)$params['product'] : 0;
        if($productId > 0)
        {
            try {
                $params['form_key'] = $this->formKey->getFormKey();
                $_product = $this->product->load($productId);
                $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
                $this->cart->save();
                $totalItems = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
                $response = [
                    'status'=>'success',
                    'message'=>'Product added to cart',
                    'total' => $totalItems
                ];
            }
            catch(\Exception $e) {
                $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        return $resultJson->setData($response);
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Could you add more details about your issue?

Comment: I just updated my question. Can you check now.

Comment: Are you using a third-party modules that could potentially affect the "Add Product to Cart" process?

Comment: Ya I am using a extension that adds free gift to cart, But I disabled it and no change. There is no other extension related to Add to Cart. I wonder why this issue not with guest users.

Comment: Updated question with code

Comment: What are the parameters that is passed to the controller? When ajax add-to-cart can be done via a few lines of Javascript code I wonder the need to create a new controller for that.