# How to override magento2 product tierprice?

Tags: magento2, product, tierprice, override-model, group-price

I want to override magento2 product tier price calcualtion logic for price type 'Percentage'. I would like to calculate the percentage amount in my own way. 
Please let me know which file I have to override inorder to achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: maybe this answer could help to override tier price logic: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/372703/54929

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will achieve by the plugins.

create a di.xml on following path:

> Company/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
     <plugin name="after_final_price" type="Company\Module\Plugin\ChangeTierPrice" sortOrder="999" disabled="false"  />
</type>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice">
      <plugin name="after_final_price_info" type="Company\Module\Plugin\ChangeTierPriceInfo" sortOrder="999" disabled="false"  />
</type>
```

Create a plugin file:

> Company\Module\Plugin\ChangeTierPrice.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Plugin;

class ChangeTierPrice
{        
    public function beforeGetFinalPrice($subject, $qty = null)
    {
        $finalTierPrice = [];
        //You need to create your own array or modify the default tier price here and set in to product object
        $subject->setData('tier_price', $finalTierPrice);

    }    
}
```

Create a plugin file:

> Company\Module\Plugin\ChangeTierPriceInfo.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Plugin;

class ChangeTierPriceInfo
{        
    public function beforeGetValue($subject)
    {
        $finalTierPrice = [];
        //You need to create your own array or modify the default tier price here and set in to product object
        $product = $subject->getProduct();
        $product->setData('tier_price', $finalTierPrice);

    }    
}
```

Comment: @Dhariya I will try this method and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice\Interceptor::setData() in /html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/ChangeTierPriceInfo.php:12

Comment: @skm Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I already solved it. Your answer helped me a lot. I will accept your answer as solution.

Comment: @DhairyaShah It's working well in PDP, but it's not working in a cart, the price isn't changing. The price always is final - no reaction when changing qty.